# How I can retrieve both the created process output and its return value?

Tags: perl

I created a script, which starts a program, for example the *ls*. I want to get the new program's output and its return status, **without starting it again**. I can grab the output, like this:

```
my $out = `ls`
```

So, how I can get the status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [$? variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%3f) holds this value.  Be sure to read the documentation carefully for how to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $cmd = "echo $$ > ./pidfile; date; sleep 10; date&";
```

./pidfile contains the pid of the child process

You may see this [monk thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=671064) as well.